# How to define a new function/struct/class if and only if it does not cause a redefinition error?

Tags: c++, c++20, sfinae, redefinition

I am generating c++ code and I need to define a new function/struct/class if and only if it does not cause a redefinition error. How can I achieve this?
I think the solution would be to try and redefine the new function/struct/class and make it fail in a SFINAE-friendly way, but I have no clue on how to do this.

For example:

```
int foo (int x, int y) { 
   return x + y;
}

int foo (int z, int a) { // Obvious redefinition here, how can I make it fail in a SFINAE friendly way?
   return x * y;
} 

template <typename T, typename U>
struct bar {};

template <typename T, typename U> // Partial template specialisation does not actually specialise the parent template, how do I make this definition fail in a SFINAE friendly way?
struct bar<T, U> {};
```

Comment: if you add `template` to `foo`, it is no longer the same function...

Comment: If you *generate* C++ code, you could move that issue to your building procedure (e.g. `Makefile`)

Comment: This is a meta programming problem that vanilla C++ just isn't able to solve unfortunately. You'll need help from an external code generator.

Comment: Sounds like you need to do something like how intellesense works where you basically have you own compiler, break down the code into all the symbols in it, and then consult that symbol table as you need to generate things.

Comment: Not a really pretty solution but you could add a `#ifdef` and `#define` to each function which is uniquely determined by the function signature. So the duplicates are resolved by the preprocessor instead. The template case is hard because as Nathan said, it would require basically a full toolchain to determine the duplicates. Maybe look into clang AST tools.